# Phoenix routing adding "controller" in the path

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Generated a new model and html with:

```
mix phoenix.gen.html Lesson lessons title:string (some more fields) student_id:references:users
```

I added in the resources line:

```
resources "/lessons", LessonContoller
```

But when i go and run `mix phoenix.routes` all the lesson routes have `_controller_` in the name like so:

```
lesson_controller_path GET /lessons ...
```

instead of:

```
lesson_path GET /lessons ...
```

They all have this extra word in them with makes all my `lesson_path` calls broken as they now need to be `lesson_controller_path`.

Is there something I'm missing or some reason as to why this happened?

Comment: Typo `LessonContoller` -> `LessonController`?

Comment: Yup......... Just found it. Was looking in all the wrong places.